Java jar unable to find valid certification path to requested target
He desarrollado una aplicación en Java versión 8 el cual hay que ejecutar mediante un Jar
Comienza con la siguiente clase:
public class DescargaMensajesEntidadesInit {
    
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DescargaMensajesEntidadesInit.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Apéndice de método generado automáticamente
        //Verificamos que se pasen tres argumentos
        if (args.length < 4) {
            log.warn("Uso: java Main <idAplicacion> <ruta_certificado> <clave_certificado> <entidad>");
            return;
        }
        
        //Primer argumento: La identificación de la aplicación
        String idAplicacion = args[0];
        //Segundo argumento: ruta al archivo de certificado
        String rutaCertificado = args[1];
        File certificado = new File(rutaCertificado);
        //Tercer argumento: clave del certificado
        String claveCertificado = args[2];
        //Cuarto argumento: entidad (debe cumplir con la expresión regular [0-9]{8})
        String entidad = args[3];
        String patronEntidad = "[0-9]{10}";
        
        //Validamos que el argumento "entidad" cumple con la expresión regular
        if (!entidad.matches(patronEntidad)) {
            log.warn("Error: La entidad debe ser un string de 10 dígitos (ejemplo: 1234567890).");
            return;
        }
        
        //Verificamos si el archivo de certificado existe y es un archivo
        if (certificado.exists() && certificado.isFile()) {
            log.info("Identificacion de la aplicacion: " + idAplicacion);
            log.info("Ruta del certificado: " + rutaCertificado);
            log.info("Clave del certificado: " + claveCertificado);
            log.info("Entidad: " + entidad);
            
            //Llamamos al Servicio descarga de mensajes
            DescargaMensajesEntrada entrada = new DescargaMensajesEntrada();
            entrada.setIdAplicacion(idAplicacion);
            entrada.setFicheroP12(rutaCertificado);
            entrada.setPasswordP12(claveCertificado.toCharArray());
            entrada.setIdEntidad(entidad);
            
            String respuesta = descargaMensajesEntidades(entrada);
            
            log.info(respuesta);
            
            
        } else {
            log.warn("El archivo de certificado no existe o no es un archivo válido.");
        }
        
    }
    
    private static String descargaMensajesEntidades(DescargaMensajesEntrada entrada)  {
        String respuesta = "";
        
        try {
            DescargaMensajesEntidadesReturn response = new DescargaMensajesEntidadesReturn();
            DescargarMensajesEntidadesService descargarMensajesEntidadesService = new DescargarMensajesEntidadesServiceImpl();
            response = descargarMensajesEntidadesService.ejecutar(entrada);
            
            respuesta = response.getRespuestaCorrecta().getOut();
            
            if("".equals(respuesta) || respuesta == null) {
                respuesta = response.getError().getTexto();
            }
        } catch (DescargaMensajesEntidadesFault_Exception e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            log.error("Problemas en el servicio de Descarga de mensajes, motivo: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        
        return respuesta;
    }

}

Si le ejecuto directamente (añadiendo los Parámetros de entrada) funciona perfectamente.
Pero cuando lo exporto en un .jar ejecutable (que así funcionará en otros entornos) lo ejecuto de la siguiente manera:

java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=CERTLEXNET.p12
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=8ba73c7240 -jar palex.jar "PALEXWS" "/certificado/CERTLEXNET.p12" "8ba73c7240" "2807906202"

Se produce el siguiente error:

sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
find valid certification path to requested target
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(Unknown
Source)
at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(Unknown
Source)
at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(Unknown
Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.executeHandshake(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:350)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:318)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.lambda$null$0(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:104)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.upgrade(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:284)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.upgrade(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:516)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.upgradeTls(InternalExecRuntime.java:195)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:173)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:192)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:113)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ContentCompressionExec.execute(ContentCompressionExec.java:147)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:174)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:123)
at es.seguridadsocial.palexws.descargarmensajes.LoginServiciosGeneralImpl.llamarWS(LoginServiciosGeneralImpl.java:184)
at es.seguridadsocial.palexws.descargarmensajes.LoginServiciosGeneralImpl.getLoginServiciosGeneral(LoginServiciosGeneralImpl.java:66)
at es.seguridadsocial.palexws.service.DescargarMensajesEntidadesServiceImpl.loginServiciosGeneral(DescargarMensajesEntidadesServiceImpl.java:106)
at es.seguridadsocial.palexws.service.DescargarMensajesEntidadesServiceImpl.ejecutar(DescargarMensajesEntidadesServiceImpl.java:62)
at es.seguridadsocial.palexws.inicio.DescargaMensajesEntidadesInit.descargaMensajesEntidades(DescargaMensajesEntidadesInit.java:75)
at es.seguridadsocial.palexws.inicio.DescargaMensajesEntidadesInit.main(DescargaMensajesEntidadesInit.java:58)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path
building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown
Source)
... 36 more Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown
Source)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown
Source)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
... 42 more

No sé si tiene que ver con las versiones de Java ya que el jar se generó con jdk1.8.0_231 y en CMD cuando ejecuto java -version me indica jre1.8.0_431
¿Podéis ayudarme?
Muchas gracias.

El error ocurre porque Java no puede validar el certificado SSL del servidor. Asegúrate de:
Importar el certificado al truststore: Usa keytool para agregar el certificado del servidor al archivo CERTLEXNET.p12.
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file <certificado>.crt -keystore CERTLEXNET.p12 -alias <alias>

Validar el truststore: Verifica que contiene el certificado esperado.
keytool -list -keystore CERTLEXNET.p12 -storepass <contraseña>

Usa el truststore correctamente: Pasa las opciones correctas al ejecutar:
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=CERTLEXNET.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<contraseña> -jar palex.jar ...

Si necesitas más ayuda, avísame! 
